# Force XML Output on cURL request

Tags: php, xml

I am using a cURL request to get XML data, which works fine in the brower but returns text in the PHP cURL. I have looked at several similar questions here and tried the answers, with no luck. Here's the code.

```
$url = 'http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.phplat=38.4247341&lon=-86.9624086&FcstType=xml';
$agent = 'Myapp/v1.0 (http://example.org;webmaster@example.org)';

$rCURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/xml');
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

$aData = curl_exec($rCURL);
$error = curl_error($CURL);

curl_close($rCURL);

if ($error)
echo ($error);
else echo ($aData);
```

Comment: If you request xml, it returns xml. You probably just output it as text, so tell browser you want xml `header('Content-Type: application/xml');` And there is the typo in `$url` `...MapClick.phplat=38.4247341&lo...` - `...php?lat=...`

Comment: That's not the problem, as the result I get is not the XML with the XML tags stripped, but a translation of the data into English with lots of stuff not in the XML. It's what I get in a browser when I ask for text format of the forecast. Thanks for spotting the typo, which was an error in copying the PHP into the post and changing the site names.

Comment: Okay, i think i don't understand you. Just ran your code and got valid xml document, just the same as i get by opening `$url` in browser (Check source code). So you can parse it, using `simpleXML` or `DOM`. Don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only thing I can think of  is something funny with the PHP setup on my hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

Your request already contains `FcstType` parameter to specify that response should be returned in XML format: `FcstType=xml`

Once XML response (string) is returned it could be parsed with [`SimpleXMLElement class`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) as demonstrated below:

```
$url = 'http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.4247341&lon=-86.9624086&FcstType=xml';
$agent = 'Myapp/v1.0 (http://example.org;webmaster@example.org)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
foreach($xml->period as $period){
    echo $period->text . "\n";
}
```